# Run argocd in a k3d cluster with local repo

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, k3d

fascinated by k8s, I'm trying to create an argocd app that is bound to a local git repository. I think local repo is a good solution for development, I read [this](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/discussions/9912) and I decide to try myself. I use k3d to provide cluster, here are the instructions I run:

```
k3d cluster create cluster1 -a 1 -v /home/myuser/workspace/argocd_tutorial:/workspace/argocd_tutorial@agent:0
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f argocd/
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=argocd
argocd app create argocd-tutorial --path "./k8s" --sync-policy auto --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --repo file:///tmp/local_repo
```

the `kubectl apply -n argocd -f argocd/` applies two .yml manifests:

- a patched argocd installation .yml file,
- a .yml file containing persistent volume and persistent volume claims to moult volume into `argocd-repo-server` container.
  Here they are:

```
#relevant parts of patched argocd installation file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: repo-server
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-repo-server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
  name: argocd-repo-server
spec:
....
        volumeMounts:
        ....
        - mountPath: /tmp/local_repo
          name: local-repo
          readOnly: true
      ....
      volumes:
      ....
      - name: local-repo
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: local-repo-pvc
    ....
```

and

```
#persistent volume and volume claim file
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: local-repo-volume
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /workspace/argocd_tutorial
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: local-repo-pvc
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: local-repo-volume
```

Despite my efforts, this is what I get back:

```
FATA[0000] rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = application spec for argocd-tutorial is invalid: InvalidSpecError: repository not accessible: repositories not accessible: &Repository{Repo: "file:///tmp/local_repo", Type: "", Name: "", Project: ""}: repo client error while testing repository: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: repository not found
```

Getting a `/bin/sh` into `argocd-repo-server` I can see the `/tmp/local_repo` directory owned by root:

```
$ ls -dl /tmp/local_repo
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 20:38 /tmp/local_repo
$ ls -al /tmp/local_repo 
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 20:38 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Feb  6 20:38 ..
```

I guess k3d mount the volume as root... Is there a way to let `argocd` user see that directory and all it contains as a git repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick fix

The issue is that you have `1 server` and `1 agent` but you are mounting volume from host only to `agent:0`

Just remove `-a 1` and mount volume using `-v /home/myuser/workspace/argocd_tutorial:/workspace/argocd_tutorial@server:0` (changed `agent:0` to `server:0`)

### Long Answer

I first it everything looks fine, but when POD is created you don't know where it will be placed as I tried to verify it I got pod on `server:0` and mounted volume is not available there.

You can see it by calling `kubectl get pods -o wide` and check column `NODE`

```
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE                    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
echo-server-deployment-66d64444b8-g26qt   1/1     Running   0          55s   10.42.1.4   k3d-cluster1-server-0   <none>           <none>
```

As you can see in my case it's `server:0` when I scaled `deployment` to 2 replicas second one appeared on `agent:0` and all data is available on that POD

You can solve it 2 ways

- (less preffered) Add volume also to `server:0` using  `-v /home/myuser/workspace/argocd_tutorial:/workspace/argocd_tutorial@server:0`
- (I suggest this one) remove `-a 1` and use `k3d cluster create cluster1 -v /home/myuser/workspace/argocd_tutorial:/workspace/argocd_tutorial@server:0` to create cluster

I think second is better because it's everything is for testing purpose, so until you really need more then one Node using just one server without agents is perfectly fine as everything is anyway on one machine and server is also running PODs.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your reply! I am curious, could a node affinity achieve the same?

Comment: Overall yes, as it can be used to force POD to be on specific node